# Mongoid-peperclip [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, spoof

I need to upload some large CSV files via mongoid-paperclip and I am getting error 
`Uploaded file2 my_file has an extension that does not match its contents`. 
In terminal I can see this error as 
 `[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: my_file.csv  (["text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values"]), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream.` `See documentation to allow this combination.` Ok, I set validation as `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :my_file` It does not help same error. 
In `application.rb` I add this line

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { jpeg: 'image/jpeg', jpg: 'image/jpeg' }
```

Then changed to this

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { csv: 'text/csv'}
```

It also does not help, same error
`Uploaded file2 my_file has an extension that does not match its contents`. 
Then I changed validation to validates_attachment_content_type :my_file, :content_type => 'text/csv'
It also did not help. Then I found some one suggesting to do this

```
`require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'         
module Paperclip         
 class MediaTypeSpoofDetector        
    def spoofed?         
      false       
    end       
  end        
end
```

But where I should do this? in which file? in which directory? (I am using rails 4.0)
If any one knows how to fix this error, please let me know! Thank you! 
       `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! this helped me!!!

```
#config/initilizers/paperclip.rb
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```